# Do posts get down-voted just for being re-edited?

Tags: discussion, edits, voting

This is possibly an opinion-based question, so there might not be an unequivocal answer to it.

But I'm still hoping that some of the frequent users of this site would be able to explain...

I often tend to edit my questions and answers over and over in order to improve them (even syntactically), under the assumption that it's also "for the benefit of the community".

I've got the feeling that at some point, users tend to down-vote the post just for being re-edited.

I have encountered this in cases where the post had quite a few up-votes and/or was accepted.

Could this be an automatic down-vote dictated by the rules of the site? Otherwise, assuming that it's not my imagination, can someone please explain what is behind this trend?

Comment: Given that you limit your post to Stack Overflow, do keep in mind that there's a Meta on Stack Overflow as well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Bart: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Lots of people consider trivially editing your question as simply a tactic to "bump" your question.  This is considered bad behavior, and you can get downvotes for that.  Keep your edits major and few rather than trivial and many.

Comment: @Won't: I didn't quite realize this until very recently. I wasn't even sure that it was indeed the reason up until now. As I mentioned in the question, I thought that improving the answer (even semantically) was "for the benefit of the community"... But I'll take it into consideration from now on... Thanks :)

Comment: You change one word a day it's abusive of the system.  Try editing and fixing *before you submit your question*.

Comment: @Won't: It's quite a pity that the system doesn't allow you to choose "don't bump my question after an edit" (as a sort of a proof of your intention not being abusive).

Comment: There is a feature request for that here.  Please, feel free to search it out and upvote it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Could this be an automatic down-vote dictated by the rules of the site?

There's no rules about voting and no automatic process that votes on posts that have had many edits.

As to why it happens, I can only speculate, but each edit bumps the question to the top of the home page again where more people can see it. By editing the post multiple times you are repeating this again and again so that more and more people see it. The more people that see the question, the more likely it is that you'll find someone who finds something in your posts that they don't like - I've no idea what that could be because voting is personal.

At one level - and I don't condone this - someone could down-vote because they've spotted that you've edited the question for the 10th time today and they're fed up of seeing it on the home page.

For questions it's probably a good idea to do something like the following:

1. Write up the question off site. Include all the information and spend some time trying to reduce the problem to the minimum required to reproduce it. You might find the solution during this time and therefore don't have to post. Check the question for grammar and spelling **before** posting.
2. Post the question and then leave it alone while monitoring it for answers and feedback. Fix any issue raised in comments but try to do that just the once (or twice).
3. Only edit if you don't have an answer after a day or so and you have some more information to add.

For answers do something similar - don't worry about being the first to answer - wait until you have a fairly complete solution before posting and only update it when necessary.

If people took more time over questions and answers we wouldn't have the quality issues that we have on some sites.

Comment: The "spend some time" issue is the problematic one (due to the "don't worry about being the first to answer" that you've mentioned). Thank you for the detailed answer.